# Hibernate fetch eagerly takes very long time

Tags: java, mysql, database, performance, hibernate

I have an hibernate query that runs on server startup to sync data from Mysql to our cache server.

Since the entity has another entity as a child which is always needed Fetch=ALL is used.

When running the query using Hibernate it takes around 3-4 minutes (It's a small table with around 600 records). When running a native SQL query it takes 0.17 sec. What am I missing?

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "hotLeadConfigId")
private Set<HotLeadSpecialPagesEntity> specialPages = new HashSet<HotLeadSpecialPagesEntity>();
```

Here is the query I am making:
[image: Query time on MySQL Phpmyadmin]

Comment: are you including hibernate initialization time in 3-4 minutes?

Comment: set your logger to debug and post the query that is executed by hibernate.. there may be more eager joins along the way

Comment: 3-4 minutes not including hibernate init :). Will send the logs in a few

Comment: Can you show us the generated SQL?

Comment: @RickJames I'm having a hard time enabling the debug log to show the generated SQL from hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to annotate it with `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` or `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)`

see [The @Fetch annotation mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-fetch-annotation) for explanation.